# Как тестировать динамичный компонент vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, typescript, юнит-тесты

Как тестировать динамический компонент?

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит изменение содержимого динамичного компонента (при нажатии туда попадает другой компонент).
Как его мокать в тестах? Как проверять что содержимое в  изменилось?

```
<component :is="name">
```

name - меняется после каждого клика

вот так я замокал компоненты, которые меняются при клике

```
FirstTabComponent: defineComponent({
            name: 'FirstComponent',
            template: '<span class="first-tab"></span>',
        }),
SecondTabComponent: defineComponent({
            name: 'SecondComponent',
            template: '<span class="second-tab"></span>',
        }),
```

сценарий для теста который я ожидаю -

1. component.find('.first-tab') - нашелся элемент
2. //emit click btn - нажимается кнопка, динамичный компонент изменился
3. component.find('.first-tab') - его больше нет на странице,
4. component.find('.second-tab') - появился второй

Но все падает на первом же шаге, first-tab не находит

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что название мокнутого компонента отличалось от того что передавалось в name.
было:

```
FirstTabComponent: defineComponent({
            name: 'FirstComponent',
            template: '<span class="first-tab"></span>',
        }),
```

должно быть:

```
FirstTabComponent: defineComponent({
            name: 'FirstTabComponent',
            template: '<span class="first-tab"></span>',
        }),
```